# Proof verification: $A = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} \ | \ x^2 + y^2 > 4\}$ is an open Set.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

I would like to prove that 
$$A = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} \ | \ x^2 + y^2 > 4\}$$
is an open set.

So we let $\mathbf{p} = (x,y)$ and prove that every $\mathbf{p} \in A$ is an inner point.

Let $\epsilon = |\lVert \mathbf{p} \rVert - 2|$ It follows that for every $\widetilde{\mathbf{p}}  \in N_{\epsilon}(\mathbf{p})$
$$\lVert \widetilde{\mathbf{p}} - \mathbf{p}  \rVert  \leq \lVert \widetilde{\mathbf{p}} \rVert + \lVert \mathbf{p} \rVert < \epsilon$$
So,
$$\lVert \widetilde{\mathbf{p}} \rVert < |\lVert \mathbf{p} \rVert - 2| - \lVert \mathbf{p} \rVert$$ 
which means,
$$ \lVert \widetilde{\mathbf{p}} \rVert = \sqrt{\tilde{x^2} + \tilde{y^2}} > 2 $$
I am not sure about the algebraic manipulation with the norm and absloute value, What are the correct steps to get to the result above?

It follows then, $\widetilde{\mathbf{p}} \in N_{\epsilon}(\mathbf{p}) \Rightarrow \widetilde{\mathbf{p}} \in A$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong. You have no reason to assert that$$\|\tilde{\mathbf p}\|+\|\mathbf p\|<\varepsilon;\tag{1}$$in general, it is false. And how do you jump from $(1)$ to $\|\tilde{\mathbf p}\|<\bigl|\|\mathbf p\|-2\bigr|-\|\mathbf p\|$?

Comment: For (1) I've used the triangular inequality (with Zero Vector) and then homogeneity property of the norm. For (2) I subtracted norm(p) from both sides. What would be the correct way to prove this? Is the choice of epsilon right?

Comment: @Sarah The choice of $\varepsilon$ is right. The rest isn't. If you want to know how to do this, please post it as another question. If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: Thanks. I've posted the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2539730/proving-a-result-involving-euclidean-norm)

Comment: @Sarah I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For another approach if you've covered continuous functions: Let $f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2$. Then f is continuous, and the pre image of $(4,\infty)$ is your set.

Comment: Yes. I am familiar with this, did you mean $(4,\infty)$?. Since per image is open, so A is open. I just would like to prove it, using definition of open sets.

Comment: I did, my mistake. Thanks.