# Proving a result, involving Euclidean norm.

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Following from a question I've posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2539673/proof-verification-a-x-y-in-mathbbr2-x2-y2-4-is-an-o#2539673),

Let $\mathbf{p} = (x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}$ and $\epsilon = |\lVert \mathbf{p} \rVert - 2|$

For every $\widetilde{\mathbf{p}}  \in N_{\epsilon}(\mathbf{p})$ : $\lVert \widetilde{\mathbf{p}} - \mathbf{p}  \rVert < \epsilon$

I would like to show, that $\widetilde{\mathbf{p}} \in A$ which means, showing that $$ \lVert \widetilde{\mathbf{p}} \rVert = \sqrt{\tilde{x^2} + \tilde{y^2}} > 2$$

What are the correct steps of manipulations with absloute value and norm to reach this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that$$\|\mathbf p\|=\|\mathbf p-\tilde{\mathbf p}+\tilde{\mathbf p}\|\leqslant\|\mathbf p-\tilde{\mathbf p}\|+\|\tilde{\mathbf p}\|$$and therefore that$$\|\tilde{\mathbf p}\|\geqslant\|\mathbf p\|-\|\mathbf p-\tilde{\mathbf p}\|.$$So,\begin{align}\|\tilde{\mathbf p}\|&>\|\mathbf p\|-\varepsilon\\&=\|\mathbf p\|-\bigl(\|\mathbf p\|-2\bigr)\\&=2.\end{align}